# I lost commits on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I wanted to add a new folder to a project in GitHub and unfortunately I used push --force. I lost my old commits and all data. I don't have it on my local repository. Is there any possibility to undo it?

```
git log
commit 0bbafc81d85d5325016728c4 ad10
git reflog
0bbafc HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): ad10
```

Comment: Check `git reflog` if you will see hashes that points out to the earlier version of your repository.

Comment: I see only last

Comment: Or by _add new project_, do you mean that you have a new project that you pushed force to another completely different project in your remote repo? :O

Comment: Can you both do `git log` and `git reflog` then update your question by showing the results of those two commands to give us a better idea of what happened? I am trying to visualize the actual scenario but I just need some more information to confirm if what I am thinking is correct.

Comment: I have project On GitHub and I wanted to add new directory there. I use push --force and on repository is only this new directory.

Comment: Okay I think I already get what happened though it is weird why it happened. Normally if you are adding new _files_ or _directories_, you will just have to `add` and `commit` those changes and `push` it without having any problems. Please try doing what I mentioned in my previous comment and edit your question by adding what you got from those two commands.

Comment: Given the results of your `git log` and `git reflog`, I guess there's no other way (not that I know of) now to retrieve your data aside from trying to [contact Github](https://github.com/contact) as @EdinMujakic suggested.

Comment: There are solutions for this if you search with google.

Answer (score 1):

If *anyone* you know has a copy of that repo, they can (force-)push their history to recover on github.